# elem is not defined in second method

Tags: jquery

```
function addQuestionToPool(elem) {    
    var body =  '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12 text-center">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="addQuestionToPoolConfirm(elem)">'+LANG.option.add+'</button>&nbsp;' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="$(\'.modal\').modal(\'hide\');">'+LANG.option.cancel+'</button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';

    showPopup("small", LANG.question.are_you_sure, body);
}

function addQuestionToPoolConfirm(elem) {
    alert(elem);
    $.ajax({
        url : URL_API + URL_POLL_QUESTION,
        type : 'post',
        data : {'user_id' : user_id, 'question' : question, 'input_type_id' : question_type, 'choices' : choices},
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (response) {

            if (response.error) {
                toastr.error(LANG.error.question_add_pool);
            } else {
                $('.modal').modal('hide');
                toastr.success(LANG.info.question_add_pool);
                poll_question_datatable.ajax.reload(null, false);
                $(elem).attr({
                    'onclick'   : '',
                    'disabled'  : true
                }).removeClass('btn-outline');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

elem is defined for addQuestionToPool, but undefined for addQuestionToPoolConfirm. Why ?

Firstly, i call the addQuestionToPool method and send the this object. I can access object in this method. But when i send to this object to addQuestionToPoolConfirm method from addQuestionToPool method, it said (this) is not defined.

And here is elem in html :

```
<button class="btn btn-icon-only btn-circle yellow-crusta btn-outline" onclick="addQuestionToPool(this);"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>&nbsp;
```

Comment: Because `elem` is not defined in the constructed HTML.

Comment: @BenM how do i access, in that method?

Comment: why are you using inline script when you already have jQuery available to do this using unobtrusive scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the button an id then in the addQuestionToPool method, you can add the Id to be passed in. Something like this:

```
onclick="addQuestionToPoolConfirm(\'' + elem.id + '\')"
```

Then it should all work